# How to extract last date from string within panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, dataframe

I need to find the last date preceding specific text within a string for each row in a panda dataframe. The text could be anywhere after the date within the string.

I have a csv file that consists of two columns. The first is a reference number (unique on each row), the other is a string that can be split on commas. Similar to this:

```
Ref No  Audit
abc123  "text1, text2, text3"
abc124  "text1, text2, text3"
```

The Ref No refers to an item in a database, the Audit is an audit of all changes made to the item. Each comma separated item within the text is a single change (eg text1 is a change, text2 is a change etc). Only when a change is made on a new date is a date appended to the start of the part of text. Each item in the Audit column looks something like this:

"01/01/2019 09:15:12 task 1 completed, task 2 completed, task 3 completed, 02/01/2019 15:26:03 task 4 completed, task 5 completed".

I am trying to find a way to identify when a specific task is completed. In the example above, if I were wanting to know when task 5 was completed, this would be 02/01/2019.

Beyond getting the data into a panda dataframe and putting the Audit text in a list, I'm lost about how to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

audit = pd.read_csv('audit_export1.csv', encoding='latin1')

audit['Audit'].apply(pd.Series)
audit['Audit'] = audit['Audit'].str.split(',')
```

I'm hoping to get a dataframe containing 2 columns; the reference and the date of change searched for.

Sorry for any mistakes or glaring errors in how I've worded the issue, I'm very new to python so would really appreciate any help you could give. I had a look at previously asked questions but couldn't find anything that answered this issue, but that may be my lack of knowledge being unable to generalise guidance.

### Edit

27/03/2019 09:34:41 John Smith The field " Handler" has been changed from Old value "" to new value "John Doe",  The field "Workflow Status" has been changed from Old value "Awaiting allocation" to new value "With Handler",27/03/2019 22:24:19 Jane Doe The field "Handler" has been changed from Old value "Jane Doe" to new value "Bill Smith",10/04/2019 04:58:43 Jill Smith The field "Workflow Status" has been changed from Old value "With Handler" to new value "Passed to Clearing Desk",10/04/2019 06:31:09 Sam Jones The field "Workflow Status" has been changed from Old value "Passed to Clearing Desk" to new value "QC",13/04/2019 08:30:49 Dave Jones The field "QC Handler" has been changed from Old value "" to new value "Dave Jones",  The field "Workflow Status" has been changed from Old value "QC" to new value "QC - With Handler",13/04/2019 09:06:36 Dave Jones The field "Workflow Status" has been changed from Old value "QC - With Handler" to new value "Passed back for re-work",17/04/2019 23:52:11 Sally Smith The field "Workflow Status" has been changed from Old value "Passed back for re-work" to new value "QC - Passed to Clearing Desk",18/04/2019 2:45:30 Bill Jones The field "Workflow Status" has been changed from Old value "QC - Passed to Clearing Desk" to new value "Complaint Handling"

#### Edit 2

```
import pandas as pd
import re
a = pd.read_csv('audit_export1.csv')
to_find = "Workflow Status"

for cases in a:
    date_list = re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ ', a['Audit Trail'])

    s = re.split(r'\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ ', a['Audit Trail'])
    task_list = [i for i in s if i != '']

    for  i, item in enumerate(task_list):
        if to_find in item:
            a['Audit Date'] = date_list[i]
```

#### Edit 3

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

to_find = 'Workflow'
a = pd.read_csv('audit_export2.csv')

a.Audit = a.Audit.str.split(',')

overall_list = []
for tmplist in a.Audit:
    dl = []
    for i in tmplist:
        i = i.strip()
        try: 
            sdate = datetime.strptime(i[:10],'%d/%m/%Y')
            dl.append(str(sdate) + i[10:])
        except ValueError: # if its NOT a date, adding the date got from the try block to the string
            dl.append(str(sdate) + i)
        dl = dl[::-1]
    overall_list.append(dl)

a['Audit_date'] = pd.Series(overall_list)
```

Comment: Will there always be a colon ':' after the date in the comma separated text? and the format will always be uniform dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: my mistake - there is no colon after the date (i'll edit the question), the format for the date is always "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Comment: ok, then the date part will always be in the first?

Comment: yes, the date I'm interested in will always be at the start of the item in the list, but not at the start of every item in the list. There may also be other dates within the items in the list. For example "task 5" could be something like "Changed the closure date from 02/02/2019 to 03/02/2019"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly on the premise that the date your are interested in, will be in the first part and always there will be a date in the very first text for each row, the below code is produced

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

a = pd.read_csv('audit_export1.csv')

a.Audit = a.Audit.str.split(',')

overall_list = []
for tmplist in a.Audit:
    dl = []
    for i in tmplist:
        i = i.strip()
        try: 
            sdate = datetime.strptime(i[:19],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
            dl.append(str(sdate) + i[19:])
        except ValueError: # if its NOT a date, adding the date got from the try block to the string
            dl.append(str(sdate) + i)
    overall_list.append(dl)

a['Audit_date'] = pd.Series(overall_list)
```

I tried to replicate the date part in those strings that dont have it and created a new column with the date inserted at the front of the strings.You can use the resulting list as you wish. For e.g the output will like below

```
print(a.Audit_date[0])

['2019-01-01 09:15:12 task 1 completed',
 '2019-01-01 09:15:12task 2 completed',
 '2019-01-01 09:15:12task 3 completed',
 '2019-01-02 15:26:03 task 4 completed',
 '2019-01-02 15:26:03task 5 completed']
```

Comment: This is so close to what I need, but when I try it, the last item in each list has 2 dates concatenated at the start
('2019-04-17 23:52:1118/04/2019 2:45:30 Task x completed') - not sure why?

Comment: Paste the string that gives this kind of output, let me have a look at it

Comment: I've edited my question with the string from the first row - it's too long to paste in here

Comment: I believe it's because the format of the date time on that example is dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss, rather than hh:mm:ss - not sure though

Comment: I don't need the time, have just changed these lines: (sdate = datetime.strptime(i[:10],'%d/%m/%Y'))...dl.append(str(sdate) + i[10:])

Comment: see edit 3 for final code. I reversed the list on each row so I could search for the first instance of the task I am looking for (to return what is actually the last occurrence). Just need to work out how to do that now. Thank you for your help, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete code it just gives you an idea on how to start, also you need to put some checks to fit another possibilities

you have a ton of options if your data format is consistent

when you load entries from csv file every entry will look like the following "02/01/2019 15:26:03 task 4 completed", you can work on this string simply like that

```
text = "02/01/2019 15:26:03 task 4 completed"
i = text.index('task')
print(text[i:])
print(text[:i-1])
```

output:

```
task 4 completed
02/01/2019 15:26:03
```

or as you said if your date format will always be the same you can use index directly:

```
print(text[20:])
print(text[:20])
```

**Edit**: to work with specific situation while one date exist for more than one task see below:

we will use regex to split the text at every date occurrence and store tasks in task list, and also find all dates and put it in other list and then remaining will be easy

```
text = "01/01/2019 09:15:12 task 1 completed, task 2 completed, task 3 completed, 02/01/2019 15:26:03 task 4 completed, task 5 completed"

import re
def get_date(task):
    date_list = re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ ', text)

    s = re.split(r'\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ ', text)
    task_list = [i for i in s if i != '']

    for  i, item in enumerate(task_list):
        if task in item:
            return date_list[i]
```

to test it

```
my_task = 'task 5'
result = get_date(my_task)
print(my_task, 'completed on', result)
```

output:

```
task 5 completed on 02/01/2019 15:26:03
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the issue I am facing is that not every item on the list will have a date. So if 3 tasks are completed on the same day only the first item would have a date. If the task I am searching for was the third one done on the day, it will not have a date within the list item.

I thought something along the lines of find the last item on the list starting with a date and get rid of all data before it, then search for the first occurrence of the task I'm looking for.

Comment: The problem with that is that the task I'm looking for may be before the last date changed

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate your help but I am struggling to get this to work in my scenario.

It works flawlessly given a single defined starting string, but I'm not sure how to get the function to run on each row of the dataframe. Apologies for my ineptitude.

Comment: see edit 2 for my attempt at amending to run on each row of the df. I have 2 issues, first my attempt doesn't work as there is a type error, I am trying to pass in the string from a['Audit Trail'], but failing. Second, there can be more than one occasion on which the task I'm looking for has been completed, so I would need to find the last time it was completed. From what I understand of the code suggested, this finds the first occurrence. Would .reverse() work?